# How to find the path to a partition?

Tags: partitioning, mount

What is the correct path for my third partition so I can create a link to share user files.

This is what I’ve done.
I have created an auto mount/dismount of a partition where I keep user files to be shared with Windows 8.1.

I created a partition `/dev/sda3` and added the label `User Files` but when I open the folder and click properties is shows: `/media/data/User Files`?

I want to create link to share files, and told to do it as follows:

```
ln -s /********/Downloads $HOME/Downloads
```

obviously only for the download folder. but what should I put for the *****

1. `/dev/sda3/downloads`
2. `/media/data/downloads`
3. Something else

Answer (score 1):

b). `/dev/sda3` is the partition that you mount, `/media/data/` is the place in the directory tree where the files on the partition are found. The mount command links the partition (or drive) to the directory tree. You can talk about the amount of space on `/dev/sda3`, or whether it is full or not, but you don't access files and directories through `/dev/sda3/`.

Comment: ok thanks. so: ln -s /dev/sda3/Downloads $HOME/Downloads would add a link to the partition. should i use terminal, xterm or uxterm?

Comment: No: `ln -s /media/data/downloads $HOME/Downloads` is the correct form. Use whichever terminal you prefer. However, there is already a Downloads folder in your home directory. You need to move (or remove) this first. If you remove it, you will lose the contents as well.

Comment: Sorry. Did it and worked, just creates a folder in a folder that takes you there. Is there a neater way of doing it so it doesn't create a folder within a folder, or even a way of redirecting the complete 'HOME'? Happy with current answer but aspire to perfection.

Comment: What folder inside what folder? Please be specific. If you do `ls -l $HOME/Downloads` you should see a reference to `/media/data/downloads` now. If not, what do you see?

Comment: /home/leandros/Documents/Documents, /home/leandros/Music/Music, etc. can't seem to copy paste from xterm, so here is what i get when i use ls -l $HOME/Downloads = total 0   when i did ls -l resulted is: total 44, drwxr-xr-x 2 leandros leandros 4096 Jan 31 20:33 Desktop (desktop in blue text), repeats for other folders...

Comment: Hard to tell where you went wrong, but the `ln` command does not create a directory. And if you had created a symbolic link, doing a `ls -l` you would expect to see something like `/home/leandros/Downloads -> /media/data/downloads`.